# C client server Redirect stdout and exec

Tags: c, server, client, buffer, exec

When i want to run exec with a simple command like ls or date it runs ok and sends back the output to client.
But when i use ls -al for example it prints to the client 4 lines and the other let's say 3 in the next loop. It's a buffer problem but i don't know how to fix it.

```
//child proccess
                    dup2(newsockfd,1);
                    dup2(newsockfd,2);
                    close(newsockfd);




                    fflush(stdout);
                    execvp(words[0],words); 
                    perror("execvp");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

This sample of code it's in a while loop so everytime it takes input from client does the parsing and gives the command to exec. I t works fine for a small output. Let's say for ls or date or pwd.
But when i do ls -al which is 7 lines it prints the first 4 and the other ones in the next loop.
I found that this issue can be fixed if i use the send command. Using the flag MSG_SENDALL but here i do a redirection and then i call the exec. 
Is there a limit between the buffer of server-client(socket buffer)??

Comment: So you're asking how to make sure the client receives the data all at once? You can't.

Comment: All the data will go to the client but not at once exactly. So there is not a way of enabling bigger buffer between socket and client?

Comment: There are ways to increase the buffer size, but you still can't make sure the client receives the data all at once, so if you want that to happen, you can't.

Comment: thanks for your replies !